# How to merge two cells in excel with same field name

Tags: excel, office365, ms-office, xlsx

[image: How to merge the two columns i.e col E and col F into a single column where the empty cells in col E is filled with the data present in the col F]

As i was trying to combine the two columns E and F as both have the same name(option 1 and option 1) into a single column where the data from the cell  col F is copied into the empty cells of column E so that i can get a single column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert 2 new columns, G & H.

In G2 enter the formula:

```
=IF(E2="",F2,E2)
```

Copy this formula for the rows where you have values in E and F. The cell addresses will change automatically.

Copy all the cells in G and Paste Values into H.
Now remove columns E, F & G.